# PHP include() breaks page layout until included file finishes database queries

Tags: php, css-float, server-side-includes

Consider the following:

incl.php

```
<div id='footer'>
  <?php
      sleep(10);
      echo "<div class='footer-float'><!-- content --></div>";
  ?>
  <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

page.php

```
<div id='main-content'>
  <!-- normal markup structure... -->
</div>
<div id='footer-wrapper'>
  <?php include('incl.php'); ?>
</div>
```

I have a page (page.php) which includes a footer, the markup for which is in incl.php. 
The real incl.php does some wordpress database stuff to look up latest posts and display a little blurb for each one - this works fine but because there is a delay (represented here by the sleep() command) making the database connections and including the required WP files, it can break the layout of my page as it can pause for up to several seconds.

While it is waiting, the floated divs in my footer mean that the container won't stretch to fit the content already loaded until incl.php finishes executing and provides the clearing div needed to stretch the container.

What I'd like to know is this: is there a way I can get PHP to serve the markup (that is, the non-dynamic stuff) first rather than doing everything sequentially like it seems to at the moment?
Otherwise, is there a better way to make this less jarring? I can't put a static height on the footer div in question as it will change depending on the content.

Any pointers much appreciated

EDIT:
Just a few points for those concerned about efficiency:

This issue crops up when I'm testing with the site running locally but the database server is remote and on the other end of an unreliable and slow net connection (if you've heard about 'hurricane bawbag' that might provide a little more context) and it is not an issue I expect to crop up much if at all in the live environment.

While points on optimising and being more efficient are appreciated, I don't see how I can justify spending time worrying about a possible 2 second delay in loading some footer content that only crops up in the testing environment - and please don't make the mistake of thinking that I haven't considered performance already purely because I've said there is a delay in loading stuff (again - LOCAL site, REMOTE database server, SLOW connection).

For the purposes of this question, please assume that the delay isn't the problem, rather that the problem is how to deal with possible delays without the page looking a mess.

Comment: You could set a min-height on your div?

Comment: This is probably not the best solution, so it's not getting posted as an answer, but you could output the page layout then load the dynamic content with AJAX...

Comment: @OptimusCrime min-height is buggy in some IEs, I usually avoid it if possible - but that might be what I end up doing :(

Comment: @DaveRandom it's not a bad idea though. thanks, might have a look if I can't find a better alternative.

Comment: @DaveRandom I included that possibility in my response and (without further info) this actually seems the best way to me. Of course, the main point to be made here is that it shouldn't take a few seconds to load a few results from the database.

Comment: @jammypeach `min-height` may be buggy, but that doesn't mean it cannot be used. IE actually treats height as min-height, so specifing both (height first) will cover IE as well.

Comment: @jammypeach : Forget about old IEs. It works fine in IE 7 and up. Using PHP like this is much worse. Then I'd consider the ajax-solution instead.

Comment: @OptimusCrime belive me, I'd love to :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the current flow without many changes you can use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
// at the begining of your application
ob_start();
// rest of the application: do any kind of output
//...

// at the end, maybe at the end of the footer
ob_end_flush();
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to have a blank page for a few seconds, the best solution would be to use Ajax: load the page normally (maybe with a min-height of the content with a loader), and load the results afterwards.

Comment: Agreed. Buffering is the way of doing it. With AJAX, you can get the data asyncronously, but you loose Accessibility (JS disabled or unsuported browsers).

Comment: Have tried this, it does help - but after a bit of playing about I think I'm going to just let it take its time and use min-height if I can - thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can process the markup from the include in a string variable, instead of echoing directly, and echo it at the footer. This way the delay will ocur before the page is totaly generated and will not cause the layout break.

**Edit:** You have to position your include in a better place.

Comment: thanks for your answer - I gave this a shot but didn't help much. can you be more specific about positioning the include?

Comment: Generating the include data in a string variable, you can put the `<?php include('incl.php'); ?>` in the header or another place that don't mess with the layout and only echo the data in the footer. But see the @daevor answer, it's better to use output cache (2 function calls and you don't have to change other things) http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a wrong idea,
I don't think any user would like to wait 10 seconds for the component to load.

Usually, if that component is not mission critical,
you should cache the database results into a static file,
then just do a simple require.

Wordpress already have lots of plugins written specifically for cache :-

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/cache
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/ (more than 2M downloads)

Comment: it doesn't take 10 seconds. I have a sleep() command in for 10 seconds so I can see the effect it has on the page without having to reload a bunch of times until the server's hamsters get tired and give me a second or two of latency. Thanks for the links but it's overkill in this case - there isn't a performance problem as such, it's just that occasionally a request takes a little longer and you can sometimes see the markup before it's decent

Comment: Every little optimization contribute to overall performance. And slow sql can bring down your site if you don't treat this seriously. ...

Comment: I am treating it seriously. Please see updated question for more context on why this happens.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is due to BOM in UTF-8. You can change coding to ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM.
Some editors like a RJTextEd can write files in this mode. I've checked. It solve my problem with BOM.